I can't get Kup to backup to my Qnap NAS
The Kup configuration allows me to point to a destination folder on my Qnap NAS. File manager can see the Folder. The Kup pop up reports that "Backup destination not available"

A good question for the makers of Kup as it is their software giving the error.

Your NAS is what....NTFS? does it require a password?  There is nothing in your q to go on for us ... so I agree: ask the maintainer

It is a Qnap branded NAS. It does require log in credentials, and I was logged in when I tested Kup. I am able to search and edit files and folders on the NAS while in Ubuntu.
